# python ImportError: cannot import name os

Tags: python, gps

Trying to run the following code and get: ImportError: cannot import name os
Trying to run the script using Python 2.7 on Debian Jessie.

```
from gps import gps 
from os import os 
from time import time

session = gps.gps()

while 1:
    os.system('clear')
    session.query('admosy') 
    # a = altitude, d = date/time, m=mode,  
    # o=postion/fix, s=status, y=satellites

    print
    print ' GPS reading'
    print '----------------------------------------'
    print 'latitude    ' , session.fix.latitude
    print 'longitude   ' , session.fix.longitude
    print 'time utc    ' , session.utc, session.fix.time
    print 'altitude    ' , session.fix.altitude
    print 'eph         ' , session.fix.eph
    print 'epv         ' , session.fix.epv
    print 'ept         ' , session.fix.ept
    print 'speed       ' , session.fix.speed
    print 'climb       ' , session.fix.climb

    print
    print ' Satellites (total of', len(session.satellites) , ' in view)'
    for i in session.satellites:
        print '\t', i

    time.sleep(3)
```

Thank you !

Comment: `import os` not `from os import os`.

Comment: `from os import os`? There is no such member or method. You are essentially looking for something called `os.os`. Instead just `import os`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been fooled by the other modules `gps` and `time` which have equally named functions/packages. This is not a general rule for all modules.

For `os`, just do

```
import os
```

and you can use `os.system` and all other functions from this package.